# Change the color of one or specific buttons on UIAlertController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have an action sheet type of UIController which shows two items, the first one is "Logout from App" and the other one is "Cancel". I want to change the font color of the button which shows "Logout from App" to red and leave the "Cancel" button with default color. How can I do that? Below is my code:

```
let cancelActionSheetButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { 
    (cancelSelected) -> Void in
    print("Cancel Selected")
}

let logoutActionSheet = UIAlertController(title:"Logout", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

let logoutActionSheetButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Logout from App", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { 
    (logoutSelected) -> Void in
}

logoutActionSheet.addAction(logoutActionSheetButton)
logoutActionSheet.addAction(cancelActionSheetButton)

self.presentViewController(logoutActionSheet, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive`.

```
let logoutActionSheetButton=UIAlertAction(title: "Logout from App", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive) { ... }
```